# How to solve liquibase checksum validation fail after liquibase upgrade

Tags: java, maven, liquibase, checksum

In my project I just tried upgrading liquibase from 3.2.2 to 3.4.2 (both the jars and the maven plugin). EDIT: same for upgrade to 3.3.x.
As a consequence, starting the application now gives the following error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
   4 change sets check sum
   src/main/resources/changelogs/xxx_add_indices_to_event_tables.xml::xxx-add_indices_to_event_tables::xxx is now: 7:0fc8f1faf484a59a96125f3e63431128
```

This for 4 changesets out of 50, all of which add indexes, such as:

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_eventtype" tableName="events">
    <column name="eventtype" type="varchar(64)"/>
</createIndex>
```

While I can fix this locally, this would be a huge pain to manually fix on all running environments. Is this a bug, or is there some workaround?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could also use the `<validCheckSum>` sub-tag of the [`<changeSet>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) to add the new checksums as valid checksums.

Also, checkout the comments on the bug [CORE-1950](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1950). You could put the log level to "debug" on both of your liquibase versions and see if you can find differences in the log output of the checksum creations.

Use subtag something like this

```
<changeSet id="00000000000009" author="system">
    <validCheckSum>7:19f99d93fcb9909c7749b7fc2dce1417</validCheckSum>
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users</sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8" file="users.csv" separator=";" tableName="users">
        <column name="active" type="boolean" />
        <column name="deleted" type="boolean" />
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

You should remember that the value of the validCheckSum tag is the new checksum for the changeset.

Answer (score 6):

```
mvn liquibase:clearCheckSums
```

Will clear the checkSums

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the checksums would be any use for you? Of course they are going to be recalculated . See related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219947/how-can-i-force-liquibase-to-recalculate-checksums-without-re-running-the-statem).
Hope that helps

Comment: how many environments do you have? 3, 4,5 liquibase does everything - you just apply a single command!

Comment: Liquibase exists in all these envs so you need to handle this case in each env eventually. Either with a liquibase specific command or fiddle around the rdbms and apply on your own changes to the liquibase tables . What about a small script , configurable with the db schema name and credentials that you could distribute to the team. the script would invoke liquibase for example .

Answer (score 3):

Using gradle `./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums`