# Backup restore and apply liquibase changes

Tags: sql, database, liquibase, checksum

We have a project where the database support is given for `Sql Server` and `Oracle` and to control the version on the database side we are using `liquibase`. Sometimes we need to bring a backup of the customer's database to our own infrastructure to investigate issues and work on it. We currently have more than `1000` `changesets` (and counting..) for database versioning, which takes a lot of time.

The problem: When we bring a backup from the customer and restore it into our local environment, we need to clear the `DATABASECHANGELOG` and re-run all the `changesets` again to force the liquibase calculate the correct `checksum`. We don't know how exactly the `liquibase` calculate it but we suppose it envolves  environments variables like database and instance name, which is different from our customer to our own env.

Question: We would like to know, how could we improve this process? Maybe configuring how the liquibase should calculate the checksum (maybe considering just the ID, Author and Script). Or recalculate the checksum to our environment. Clearning the `DATABASECHANGELOG` and re-runing all the changesets is consuming a lot of time and make it difficult to maintenance.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the customers actually changing the database or table structures? Or are you just trying to load the customer data to replicate the issue? If it's the second I'm not sure liquibase needs to be involved at all.

Comment: The customer does not change the database, we just restore it on our environment and if we just runs the differences, it will break on the firsts changesets because of the checksum. To workaround on it, we have to clear the databasechangelot and re-run, when it works, but consume a lot of time (and sometimes, timeout problems on our devops pipeline).

Comment: Yes, but what I'm suggesting is maybe you don't need to restore it via liquibase. Create an empty database with liquibase and then use one of the data import tools for the RDBMS you're using? Otherwise use the liquibase client to clear the checksums? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30221141/7112871

Comment: Let me ask, looking at this solution for `clearCheckSum` I have seen that in the next update the checksum will be generated. What is the difference of clearning the databasechangelog and doing this?